# Why will this algorithm print a fibonacci/tribonacci sequence for all seeds except 0 and 1?

Tags: java, fibonacci

I am trying to print a finite amount of a tribonacci sequence(Where the value of any term is equal to the sum of the three preceding terms i.e. [2,3,5,10,18,33...]) using seed values gained from user input. Using ANY OTHER positive values besides 0 and 1, the code always works, as shown below:

```
2
3
5
Printing...
[2, 3, 5, 10, 18, 33, 61, 112, 206, 379, 697, 1282, 2358, 4337, 7977, 14672, 26986, 49635, 91293, 167914]
Process finished with exit code 0
```

But with 0, 1, and 1 as the seeds, I get:

```
0
1
1
Printing...
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is the code(I'm aware of the overly explicit comments, it's for a reason):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tribonacci {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.printf("Hello!\n");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.printf("The purpose of this program is to display the first twenty terms of either a Fibonacci sequence or a Tribonacci sequence\n");
    System.out.printf("To start, type \"F\" for Fibonacci or \"T\" for Tribonacci:\n");//Give prompt options
    Scanner seqeuence = new Scanner(System.in);
    String typeseq = seqeuence.next();//get user input, based on ^ prompt ^
    printSequence(typeseq);
}

private static void printSequence(String typeOfSequence) throws InterruptedException {


    //checks for which kind of sequence they want to print based on above prompt
    switch (typeOfSequence) {
        case "T"://if user types "T"

            System.out.printf("You have chosen to print the first twenty terms of the Tribonacci sequence\n");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.printf("We will need the seed terms for this to work, so input THREE non-negative integers, in numerical order:\n");
            Scanner getTrib = new Scanner(System.in);
            int[] tSeeds = new int[3];//scans for three seeds from the user, stores in an array of size 3

            //put each seed term into an array, in order to perform arithmetic on the elements later
            for (int i = 0; i < tSeeds.length; i++) {
                tSeeds[i] = getTrib.nextInt();
            }

            int[] newTSeq = new int[20];//final array to be printed
            newTSeq[0] = tSeeds[0];
            newTSeq[1] = tSeeds[1];
            newTSeq[2] = tSeeds[2];
            int incrementT = 0;//used to traverse the array and move which seeds should be summed
            for (int itemT : newTSeq) {

                if (itemT == tSeeds[0] || itemT == tSeeds[1] || itemT == tSeeds[2]) {
                    continue;

                } else {
                    newTSeq[3 + incrementT] = newTSeq[incrementT] + newTSeq[incrementT + 1] + newTSeq[incrementT + 2];
                    ++ incrementT;
                }
            }

            System.out.printf("Printing...\n");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(newTSeq));//terms are converted into strings to be printed

            break;

        case "F"://if user types "F"

            System.out.printf("You have chosen to print the first twenty terms of the Fibonacci sequence\n");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.printf("We will need the seed terms for this to work, so input TWO non-negative integers, in numerical order:\n");
            Scanner getFib = new Scanner(System.in);
            int[] fSeeds = new int[2];//scan user input of TWO integers into an array that holds TWO integers

            //put each seed term into array for later computation, like above
            for (int i = 0; i < fSeeds.length; i++) {
                fSeeds[i] = getFib.nextInt();
            }

            int[] newFSeq = new int[20];//final array to be printed
            newFSeq[0] = fSeeds[0];
            newFSeq[1] = fSeeds[1];
            int incrementF = 0;
            for (int itemF : newFSeq) {
                if (itemF == newFSeq[0] || itemF == newFSeq[1]) { //if the iterator is on one of the seeds, don't sum
                    continue;
                } else {
                    newFSeq[2 + incrementF] = newFSeq[incrementF] + newFSeq[incrementF + 1];//sums the two preceding terms
                    incrementF++;
                }
            }

            System.out.printf("Printing...\n");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(newFSeq));//convert all array values to strings, to be printed

            break;

        default://if neither case is satisfied, print this message
            System.out.printf("Restart the program. Next time, input the SUGGESTED prompt items \"F\" for Fibonacci or \"T\" for Tribonacci");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Because `if (itemT == tSeeds[0] || itemT == tSeeds[1] || itemT == tSeeds[2]) { continue;`. Now the question is: why did you put that line in there at all?

Comment: You have overcomplicated your `for` loop. Just use a normal `for` with the counter starting at 3 and going to the end.

Comment: @v010dya Thank you very much. I don't know how I decided on such a complicated solution. Works great.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Hehe I mistakenly left that there. Removing in addition to the other advice worked out perfectly!

Comment: Hi @C.Horace Can you please consider my answer.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve] - if it's the Tribonacci sequence that's the problem, you don't need the Fibonacci part. Likewise, you don't need any user input - you can just hard-code it. You don't need any Thread.sleep calls, and you don't need any kind of restarting.

Comment: @JonSkeet If you'll forgive me, I'm fairly new to this site, and am not fully aware of all the etiquette surrounding the asking and answering of a question. I'll try to keep what you said in mind, but no need to be lewd.

Comment: I don't see that I was lewd at all. I was suggesting how you can massively improve your question. (You can still do that - you don't need to wait until you ask a next question; edit this one.) Please read [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: @JonSkeet My apologies for misunderstanding then. It's just that I have come across many people who are very unfriendly to new users who are trying their best. Thanks for the genuine help

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have this strange condition

```
if (itemT == tSeeds[0] || itemT == tSeeds[1] || itemT == tSeeds[2]) {
    continue;
}
```

which means you don't assign anything to the `newTSeq` array if any of `tSeeds[0]`,`tSeeds[1]` or `tSeeds[2]` is 0 (since `itemT` is `0` by default for all the elements of `newTSeq`, and in the case of 0,1,1 input you only change `newTSeq[1]` and `newTSeq[2]` to `1` prior to your loop).

I'm not sure what this condition is supposed to do. You can probably remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace the following code:-

```
int[] newTSeq = new int[20];//final array to be printed
Arrays.fill(newTSeq, -1);
newTSeq[0] = tSeeds[0];
newTSeq[1] = tSeeds[1];
newTSeq[2] = tSeeds[2];
```